# Remove encoded html and add line break

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have been trying to solve this one for hours now but got no luck. The XML looks like-

```
    <description>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat

     &lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Section B: China&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

     &lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
     sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
     eratLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
     eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat&lt;/p&gt;

      &lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Section C: Himalayan Studies&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

     &lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
     sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
     eratLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
     nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore a aliquyam erat&lt;/p&gt;

     </description>
```

I want the output to be clean without the encoded `<p>` or `<b>` tags but also insert a line break before the sections by replacing `&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;` with `<br/>` . So output will look like

```
<description>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
       sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat

       <br/>Section B: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
       sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
       eratLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam no
       eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat

        <br/>Section C: Himalayan Studies Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 

       sadipscing sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore m   
       ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
       nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore a aliquyam erat

         </description>
```

I have tried using the replace function but was not able to add line breaks.
Also tried using translate but no luck

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(.,
            translate(.,
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ',
            ''),
            '')"/>
```

Any help on how to approach this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **XSLT 3.0** solution that uses the **[parse-xml()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml)** function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <!--standard identity template-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--Concatenate encoded <p> element to ensure that it is well-formed 
                XML with a document element when parsed.
                Use parse-xml() to parse the encoded markup as a parsed document.
                Apply-templates to the parsed document--> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(concat('&lt;p&gt;', ., '&lt;/p&gt;'))"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove <p> and <b> elements -->
    <xsl:template match="p | b">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--for every <p> element that has a <b> element, generate a <br/> -->
    <xsl:template match="p[b]">
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

An inelegant (but working) solution:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(replace(., 
                     '&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;', '¶'), 
                     '(&lt;)(.*)(&gt;)', ''), 
                     '¶', '&lt;br/&gt;')" 
              disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (which is way uglier)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="description/text()">
        <description>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;">
                        <xsl:matching-substring/>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;p&gt;">
                                <xsl:matching-substring/>
                                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;/p&gt;">
                                        <xsl:matching-substring/>
                                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            </xsl:analyze-string>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </description>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it outputs what the OP wants.

Comment: I don't think having the identity template makes any difference when you're matching the only existing element. In any case, your result has markup residues after the section title, e.g.`...China&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;` and around the following paragraph: `&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum  ... aliquyam erat.&lt;/p&gt;`. That doesn't match the OP's request: *"I want the output to be clean without the encoded `<p>` or `<b>` tags "*.

Comment: It just so happens that the input panel and output panel in my editor has the same XML. what is happening to me?

Comment: Is this an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

An **XSLT 2.0** solution that uses the **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)** function to split the encoded HTML where `&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;` occurs. For each of the tokenized items, it creates the `<br/>` element (if it's not the first item in the sequence) and removes any of the remaining encoded markup from that item with the **[`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)** function.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;')">
                <xsl:if test="position()>1">
                    <br/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '&lt;.*?&gt;', '')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```